# jQuery Tabs - Populate Tab Panel with URL content

Tags: jquery

I need help regarding jQuery Tabs.

I have following code that prints tabs

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery UI URL Tabs</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#myTabs" ).tabs();
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <div id="myTabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#t1">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#t2">Page 2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="t1"></div>
            <div id="t2"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to load content of tabs dynamically with URL for example
t1 = http://www.google.co.in
t2 = http://www.yahoo.com

Can anybody please help?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really try to solve that problem yourself, did you? Please have a look at the jQuery documentation and look for $.load() or $.ajax()

Answer (score 0):

You can't load a full page into Jquery Tab. You can load a simple html or content with Ajax.

Try to insert Iframe into Jquery Tab and then load url into Tab.